# Make unique readable string out of a long integer

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, converters

I have long integers numbers like this: 5291658276538691055

How could I programmatically convert this number to a 4-6 capital letters only that is a unique combination that can also be reversed to get back to the number?

For example using OBJ-C.

Comment: What's the largest integer you expect to get?

Comment: Largest would be 20 digits

Comment: 18 digits would be the smallest

Comment: That's not happening unless you can restrict the range on inputs. A-Z 6 chars biggest number you'll get is 141167095653375

Comment: 7 chars would do (26^6) - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the numbers to Base 26 (Hexavigesimal - snappy name!)

The [Wikipedia article on Hexavigesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal) gives example code in Java - you should be able to adapt this pretty easily.

NB: You cannot get the long number you mentioned down to 4-6 capital letters only using a conversion algorithm (your example in Base 26 is BCKSATKEBRYBXJ).  If you need conversion that short, you only have two options:

- Lookup tables (store mappings, e.g. 5291658276538691055 = ABCDEF).  Obviously only useful if you have a discrete set of numbers.
- Including additional characters (e.g. lower case + numbers).

Comment: It'll end up being 14 digits in length. Base 62 gives you 11.

Comment: OP asked for capitals only, but updated the answer to include the possibility of a lookup table if this is suitable.

Comment: Thank you Richard. This did the trick even though 6 chars is impossible is the straightest forward solution

Answer (score 3):

There are 26 capital letters;

6 of them could represent 26 ^ 6 numbers (308915776);

So, no. You are trying to map a much larger range of numbers into a much smaller range, it cannot be reversible.

Also, `log 5291658276538691055 / log 26` is less than 14, so if 14 letters is good for you, just transform the number into 26-based and map the digits to letters.

And one more thing - if the range of numbers is small enough, you could do some manipulation on the numbers (e.g., just subtract the min) and encode it, which will cost you less digits.